# Two dll function calls only work with random print() in between

Tags: python, ctypes

I use a camera SDK with a DLL (ctypes.WinDLL).

```py
camera_path = 'cam://0'.encode('utf-8')
handle = xdll.XDLL.open_camera(camera_path, 0, 0)
# (The handle returned is 1)
xdll.XDLL.set_property_value_f(handle, b'IntegrationTime', c_double(2500))
```

This gives an the following error:

```py
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000001
```

The weird thing is, that the code works as expected with a random print in between:

```py
camera_path = 'cam://0'.encode('utf-8')
handle = xdll.XDLL.open_camera(camera_path, 0, 0)
# (The handle returned is 1)
print('random print')
xdll.XDLL.set_property_value_f(handle, b'IntegrationTime', c_double(2500))
```

Any idea what `print()` does to prevent such an error?

If `time.sleep(1)` is used instead of `print()` it shows the error, so the time spent on printing should not make a difference.

EDIT:
The interesting lines from the header file:

```
typedef int            XCHANDLE;    ///< Handle type used to identify an initialised session to a camera.

XCHANDLE    IMPEXPC XC_OpenCamera                   (const char * pCameraName = "cam://default", XStatus pCallBack = 0, void * pUser = 0);  ///< @sa XCamera::Create
ErrCode     IMPEXPC XC_SetPropertyValueF            (XCHANDLE h, const char * pPrp, double dValue, const char * pUnit);
```

methods in xdll.XDLL:

```
    open_camera = _xenethDLL.XC_OpenCamera
    open_camera.restype = c_int32  # XCHANDLE


    set_property_value_f = _xenethDLL.XC_SetPropertyValueF
    set_property_value_f.restype = c_ulong  # ErrCode
    set_property_value_f.argtypes = (c_int32, c_char_p, c_double)
```

Comment: How about `sys.stdout.flush()`? I _think_ that's what print calls.

Comment: Most likely, a duplicate: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: @Peter no sys.stdout.flush() doesn't help...

Comment: @CristiFati not sure, maybe the added info helps...?

Comment: You are not supplying the required `pUnit` parameter to `XC_SetPropertyValueF`.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a required parameter (`char * pUnit`) to the argtypes.
Therefore, i got some weird/undefined behaviour.

Now, after i added the parameter the code executes as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).